# Three.js - Updating godrays light source position

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I'm using a sprite as a light source for a god rays post-processing pass in Three.js. 
However, when I update the sprite position, the post-processed light stays at its initial position, resulting in the sprite moving without its god rays.

I tried resetting the light source position after initialization on each frame like so:

```
...    
PostProcessor.godRaysPass.lightSource.position.set(sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y, sprite.position.z)
PostProcessor.composer.render(clock.getDelta());
```

or

```
...    
godRaysPass.lightSource = sprite
PostProcessor.composer.render(clock.getDelta());
```

But nothing worked, and by looking at the GodRays class I'm not sure it's even possible to update the light source position without modifying the class first, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I did some digging and came to this:

Moving the source light doesn't cause any problem, the godrays do follow the sprite source when you change the sprite position.
**The problem actually came from the fact that the source light was inside a rotating group**.
By removing the light source from the group and rotating it along the same axis as the group, the godrays behave as expected.